# How are RDM patterns for reactions in the KEGG database constructed?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, cheminformatics

With respect http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?rp:RP00167 
can anyone tell me how the RDM pattern were obtained?? 
 Information what RDM is given here: 
http://www.genome.jp/kegg/reaction/ 

Note: This may be a silly question to all chemists, but not for me, i am a computer science student , and my research field in bioinformatics and so i have to study both biology and bit of chemistry, so please just dont close the question or be harsh on me, I have very little knowledge in chemistry and also googling doesn't help much. I asked this question in Biology forum, they closed the question and asked me to ask it here

Comment: Did you have a look at [Computational Assignment of the EC Numbers for Genomic-Scale Analysis of Enzymatic Reactions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja0466457) by *Minoru Kanehisa*, the founder of KEGG (Kyoto Encyclopedia of Genes and Genomes)?

Comment: If you are anywhere near a college or university, you will probably be able to access the paper suggested by @KlausWarzecha. The Journal of the American Chemical Society is one of the most prominent chemistry journals in publication.

Comment: @jerepierre Definitely! In addition, the J. Chem. Inf. Model. paper suggested in my answer is available free of charge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my impression, there is no RDM **value**, but a RDM **pattern**!

This is about mapping atoms is a reactant and a product by assigning **R** (*reaction center*), **D** (*difference atoms*) and **M** (*matched atoms*) in both compounds. Pairs for **R**, **D**, and **M** are separated by colons. The pattern is thus given as

**R**(reactant)-**R**(product) : **D**(reactant)-**D**(product) : **M**(reactant)-**M**(product),

where a an asterisk marks a void centre.

In order to figure out how these patterns are retrieved, you definitely want to have a look at *Modular Architecture of Metabolic Pathways Revealed by Conserved Sequences of Reactions*, a freely available article by *Minoru Kanehisa* (KEGG founder), published in *J. Chem. Inf. Model.*, **2013**, *53*,613-622 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ci3005379)). Don't forget to read the [Supporting Information](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/ci3005379/suppl_file/ci3005379_si_001.pdf), particularly the sections on **KEGG atom types** and  **RDM chemical transformation notation**.